# How can I create MS SQL-server session (connection) variables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I would like to create "session" variables right after opening a connection. Variables like USERID or IDADDRESS which I can later refer to in a trigger. The trigger is designed to record changes in an audit file for historical purposes, but I want to record which user made the change.

I am thinking of variables so it would have minimal overhead.

Is that possible and how do I do it? If not, any other suggestions?
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temp table (`#temp` or `##temp`). Session or server scope - depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For auditing purposes you don't need "session variables", you can use built-in functions like SYSTEM_USER, ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), user, @@spid, HOST_NAME()